# What does here "creepy puppy dog" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

He is always looking to Walt for some sort of appreciation like a really creepy puppy dog. To be honest, I did not really get what the author wanted to say with this sentence. Can someone explain it in easier words, especially the meaning of "creepy puppy dog"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A puppy dog is always seeking its master's attention and favor.
There is not enough information in this quote to suggest why his behavior is creepy.

Comment: He also sets his obsessive mind on Walter and seems to look up to the man greatly and frequently does everything he can to get Walt's attention

Comment: Oxford Dictionaries gives one definition of the noun _creep_ as _a person who behaves obsequiously_. I suspect _creepy_ is used in this sense rather than the more usual _causing fear and unease_.

Comment: I'm trying to find a reference to creepy being used to mean creep-ish. Could you link for me? I think those are totally different words.

Comment: I didn't find one, but a puppy is much more likely to be obsequious than spooky!